# Set up nginx and node apps on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, nginx, https

Here's the situation -

- node express app1 (backend app - REST API server) - running on port 8888 -
  bunch of POST routes (auth, api, download, upload..) - communicating with mysql server - maintained by developer #1
- node (webpack, react) app2 (front end app) running on port 80 - maintained by developer #2

This week we set up nginx and HTTPS (via Let's encrypt), which means that when a user comes to the www.oursite.com - it is redirected to the https site with nice green lock and secure site. So far so good. However, when the user enter her email, the app2 is supposed to call app1 and email with registration token should be sent. This worked well before we try to set up nginx - and use http on both apps. Now this call is not happening. This is our nginx setting:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/oursite.com/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name oursite.com www.oursite.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/oursite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/oursite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot




    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    # Redirect non-https traffic to https
    # if ($scheme != "https") {
    #     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    # } # managed by Certbot

}
```

My question (developer #1) - should I replace all routes in my app (backend app - app1 - backend) to be https  instead of http? [Apparently Chrome is not calling http request](https://taylorpetrick.com/blog/post/https-nodejs-letsencrypt) from https site (as is our case)
 and how should I setup the nginx then - I belive I should add another location part in nginx setting.
If there are other suggestions please let us know.

Comment: Yeah, I think you should be able to use the loopback IP address (or localhost) to send an https request to app2

Answer (score 0):

Each port must get its own server{ } block, so port 80 gets one and port 443 get another each with a listen directive to the respective port ... in above you have both ports in the same server{ } block

If the app is exposed to the internet they should be using https and if not their incoming traffic using http which is port 80 block must get redirected to send traffic to 443 ... so your nginx config file will look similar to

```
server { 

    listen  80 ;
    listen  [::]:80 ;

    server_name example.com, www.example.com;

    # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS 
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {

    listen  443 ssl ;
    listen  [::]:443  ssl ;

    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/oursite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/oursite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {

        # direct traffic to my server on its host IP and port
        proxy_pass http://172.19.0.5:3000/; # notice http not https
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

In your case looks like app1 is not exposed to the internet and so does not appear in your nginx config ... it only receives http traffic downstream from app2  ... all of above config is only for your app2 ... incoming internet traffic using secure https port 443 (or port 80 which gets redirected to 443) receives what is called TLS termination ... apps shielded from the internet by the nginx TLS termination receive http traffic not https which is fine since the app ports are not visable from the internet ... and so your app2 gets http traffic not https

Comment: Thanks for answers, but do i need an https server on node express (app1) or can I somehow manage with http on app1 - since app2 is on https and is calling app1, which is (currently) not on https?? hope I am clear with my issues here

Answer (score 0):

We got this to work by setting the app1 (backend up) as https as well. However, this works in all major browser, except for firefox. SO I guess I shiuld post a new question now. The site is not letting through the form on firefox - but only if the address does not have www. That means https://testsite.com -> not working, https://www.testsite.com working ok. But is working ok on all other browsers.